# EASY PYTHON SELENIUM: How do I download an mp4 WITHOUT using urllib?

Tags: python, selenium, urllib

I'm trying to download this video: https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
link = "https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, 'video.mp4')
```

I'm getting:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Is there another way to download an mp4 file without using urllib?

Comment: If server decides that you don't have access to a file it does not really matter what tools you use to download file - you can't influence server's decision from the client by simply picking different library to execute HTTP GET request. So please [edit] the question to clarify what you need to get 200 response from the server for that file and how library you use currently does not allow you to construct request in a way that makes server happy.

Comment: servers may check many elements to block bots/spamers/hackers - first they may check header `User-Agent` and many tools use value different then in real browser - and servers may see this difference.  Next server may check other headers, cookies, JavaScript settings, etc.

Comment: I have no problem to download with `requests`

Comment: @furas PLEASE EXPLAIN

Comment: there is nothing to explain `r = requests.get(ur)` and you can get bytes `r.content` and write in file in `"bytes mode"` with `open(..., "wb")`, `write()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem to download with module `requests`

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4'

response = requests.get(url)

with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as f:  # use `"b"` to open in `bytes mode`
    f.write(response.content)       # use `.content` to get `bytes`
```

---

It was small file ~10MB but for bigger file you may download in chunks.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4'

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(10000):  # 10_000 bytes
        if chunk:
            #print('.', end='')  # every dot will mean 10_000 bytes 
            f.write(chunk)
```

Documentation shows [Streaming Requests](https://2.python-requests.org/projects/3/user/advanced/#streaming-requests) but for text data.

---

`url` is a `string` so you can use `string`-functions to get element after last `/`

```
filename =  url.split('/')[-1]
```

Or you can try to use `os.path`

At least it works on Linux - maybe because Linux also use `/` in local paths.

```
import os

head, tail = os.path.split(url)

# head: 'https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05'
# tail: 'sample-mp4-file.mp4'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Do you mind letting me know how I would preserve the original name? Also, what do you mean by chanks? Could you give sample code if it was 1 GB?

Comment: `url` is a `string` so you can use `string`-functions to get element after last `/` - ie. `url.split('/')[-1]`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you mind also letting me know how to download in chunks?

Comment: I have to check it in requests documentation.

Comment: I added it to answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Last question. Is there a difference between small chunks and big chunks? Does it affect bitrate/quality etc?

Comment: I don't know - smaller chunk needs to run code/loop more times and it may run little longer (but you may no see difference). Other problem can be memory. Bigger chunk needs more memory, and I'm not sure but socket buffer may have some limit.

Comment: if I use `iter_content(None)` then `len(chunk)` sometimes gives even `32768` which is `2^15` - and this may be the limit.

Comment: Can you let me know whether I should use iter_content(10000) or iter_content(None) ?

Comment: you would have to experiment with different values and measure times - but it may make not so big difference.